# oven not igniting

Tags: electrical, oven

(Updated.)

I have a gas stove and oven with no pilot light (so they ignite using electricity). The stove and broiler (at the top of the oven cavity) are lighting fine, but the oven is not (at the bottom of the oven cavity; I do smell gas when it's on, though). Any ideas on what the problem/solution may be?

Here are some descriptions of symptoms in answer to clarifying questions that have been asked in comments:

- I do not hear a clicking/sparking noise when I turn the oven on.
- It's a Maytag oven, model number CGR3742CDC.

Comment: Do you hear a clicking/sparking noise when you turn the oven on? Could you indicate the make and model of the oven.

Comment: @Tester101, thanks. I've added that to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out the igniter (? the thing that glows) was not lighting up fully, so the gas didn't come on right. I replaced it and all's well.